# AWK or bash profile is adding unwanted color codes to stdout

Tags: linux, shell, awk, bash

Hi I'm using AWK to produce a bunch of submissions to our cluster.

```
$ls myfiles* | awk '{for(i=1;i<101;i++){print("qsub -d `pwd` -v FILE="$1",NUM="i" -N "$1" run.qsub")}}'
```

produces something like -

```
qsub -d `pwd` -v FILE=myfiles100.txt,NUM=100 -N myfiles100.txt run.qsub
```

EXCEPT the variable $1 (myfiles100.txt) that was substituted in awk statement, is highlighted in green syntax. I don't know if this is due to my bash profile or something with AWK, but I've never seen it before. The problem comes when I redirect this to stdout.

```
$ls myfiles* | awk '{for(i=1;i<101;i++){print("qsub -d `pwd` -v FILE="$1",NUM="i" -N "$1" run.qsub")}}' > somefile.txt
```

And when I open somefile.txt

```
qsub -d `pwd` -v FILE=^[[0m^[[32mmyfiles100.txt^[[0m,NUM=100 -N ^[[0m^[[32myfiles100.txt^[[0m run.qsub
```

The color codes are inserted as well, but this causes confusion when I execute these jobs to the scheduler. I can remove the color codes with a nice sed command.

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"
```

But there has to be some setting I'm missing to make things easier.

Comment: almost certainly an env var for `ls`. use `ls --color=never -other opts`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! Of course that was the problem. global bash had ls color option set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You're not supposed to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

In your specific case, it's much better to just do this:

```
printf '%s\n' myfiles* | awk '{for(i=1;i<101;i++){print("qsub -d `pwd` -v FILE="$1",NUM="i" -N "$1" run.qsub")}}'
```

Here's a pure Bash possibility to achieve what you want:

```
for file in myfiles*; do
    for i in {1..100}; do
        printf 'qsub -d "$PWD" -v FILE=%q,NUM=%d -N %q run.qsub\n' "$file" "$i" "$file"
    done
done > somefile.txt
```

where I used `%q` to print out the filename, just in case the filename contains spaces or other funny symbols: these will be properly quoted (of course, this assumes that your commands will be executed by Bash on the cluster). I also used `"$PWD"` instead  of your `` `pwd` ``, so that you'll save a subshell each time the command is executed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the `ls` you're using is an alias for `ls --color` . You can check this with `which ls`. One way around this would be to specify the full path when using `ls`. In most cases it's `/usr/bin/ls`.

Comment: This is what `command` is for. So `command ls` instead of `ls`. Also `\ls` works to avoid aliases.

Comment: I've always used `alias ls="ls --color=auto"`